# In what space does an expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]$ take values in?

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{H}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space and $X:\Omega\to\mathsf{E}$ be a random variable with well-defined expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega)
$$

> What values does $\mathbb{E}[X]$ take? What is the space of values of this expectation? I am guessing $\mathbb{E}[X]\in\mathsf{E}$ but I couldn't find any reference.

Comment: In the case of Banach spaces, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral

Comment: What does 'well-defined' mean here? There exist real valued r.v's $X$ with $EX=\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Usually I've seen people write "well-defined" as $\mathbb{E}[|X|] < \infty$ which I guess means that the Lebesgue integral exists

Comment: In your context neither the integral nor $|X|$ make any sense. You should improve the question by adding some hypothesis to $(E, \mathcal E)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what are the minimal assumptions on $(E, \mathcal{E})$ for the expectation to exist? I've never seen this kind of results

Comment: In the simplest case, $E = \mathbb{R}$. The integral extends component wise to $E = \mathbb{R}^n$ valued functions. When $E$ is an arbitrary Banach space, things are more subtle.

Answer (score 3):

The integral does not exist for a general measurable space $E$. You need some form of addition to define it. In this case (for example $E$ is a Banach space), you do have $\mathbb E[X]\in E$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mind explaining why you need a form of addition? I understand a Banach space is a complete normed space, but not sure how these are related

Comment: How can you define the integral of simple functions if $E$ is not a vector space? And even if $E$ has a vector space structure, how can you define the integral as the limit of something if you don't have any topological structure on $E$?

Comment: @Bob Aaaah I see your point! You need $(F, +_F, \times_F)$ to be a field, $(E, +_E, \times_{FE}, F)$ to be a vector field over $F$ with binary operation "addition" $+_E$ and scalar multiplication $\times_{EF}$ to sum or subtract simple functions. And similarly, you need norms for limits etc

Comment: Before trying to state a vast generalization, study some of the work that has been done where $E$ is a Banach space.